# Use the script to export values with offset by one column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to use the `exportRange` Function and set the target to off center by one column.

How can I accomplish this?

```
function exportRange() 
    {
   var import = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KTvAvC6UCePjyEiOmyTlCokdiHMwYbKBJRAKDxaAIPQ');
   var ss = import.getSheetByName('Business Division Master Contact List');

   var SRange = ss.getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow(), 16);         //Get full range of data
   var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();    //get A1 notation id the range
   var SData = SRange.getValues();          //get the data values in range

   var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bfew3H4gluutxuo1tDRr8rwNCZHSuw16oHYthT_f8CM');
   var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Business Contact List'); // ts = target sheet
   ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);   //set the target to the source values
  }
```

Comment: Try any of the offset method of [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Antwain? What happened to your question on StackOverflow about `If "Rampup" Position matches "Validation" Position and Hire Date falls within range of "Ramp Up Dates" then the corresponding Ramp Up Amount should be returned to F.` It seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

As Rubén suggested, use the [offset method of class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)):

```
ts.getRange(A1Range).offset(0, 1).setValues(SData);
```

This offsets the range to the right by 1 column.